# Windows XP force authentication on RDP

Tags: windows, windows-xp, remote-desktop

I've been trying now for a while, but cannot sort this out...

I am running two Windows XP guest machines on VirtualBox and if I connect to either of them via RDP, they log straight into the desktop without authenticating. It just goes straight into the Windows XP desktop without asking for a username of password... I cannot for the life of me figure out how to force it to authenticate?

I can log onto the Host machine via RDP fine and it authenticates.

I 'have' installed PowerToy for XP so that the machine boots automatically without asking for a password, but I need this functionality.

How can I force RDP on the Windows XP guest machines to ask for a username and password?

Thanks in advance for help on this one!

Comment: If you've saved RDP shortcuts to the VMs, ensure you haven't saved/set credentials in the shortcut (to check, edit the RDP connection and hit "Show Options").

Comment: Hi, no it is not that, as I have tried logging in via other machines (not just my own) and it does the same thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stored username, on an XP system, is in a text file with the system name or "default.RDP", usually found in My Documents.  Edit that file to remove the username.

Alternatively, run Remote Desktop (mstsc.exe) so that the program opens, select the system you want to change, click the Options button:

[image: RDP basic]

then remove the credentials & uncheck the box for "Allow me to save credentials", and then be sure to click "Save".

[image: RDP2]

This assumes that you haven't explicitly made a registry edit to cause the system to pass through credentials.

Comment: Hi, this is connecting TO the Windows XP (machines) not FROM them. Just to clarify, I have a Windows & machine runnign VirtualBox which has two Windows XP machines on it (not sure how relevant this is). 

If I attempt to connect TO either of these two machines, from any other machine, it logs straight into the desktop without asking for any authentication. 

It does not appear to be an issue of the user/pass being stored on the machine as I have tried from other machines and it still just logs straight in. 

Which registry setting would I need to check re: your end comment?

Thanks.

Comment: If you have a single user account on the XP system, and especially it's "Home" version, there is no requirement to enter a password.  What you should do is remove the powertoy and use "autoadminlogon" (registry settings for username & password) for the machine login you need;  then RDP will prompt for the password for any other connections, but the console session won't.  Sorry that I misunderstood & thought you were logging in -from- XP as well.

Comment: Hi, I have tried this, but it still bypasses the login request when connecting via RDP.

I disabled PowerToy and made the changes in regedit and entered the username and password.

I am using Windows XP Professional.

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Add a new account with a password.

Comment: Hi, I did this and added a new user account with a password, ensured that the credentials weren't stored in the local RDP yet it still just logs straight into the XP desktop! Any further ideas? Many thanks again for your help!

Comment: I've partially solved this by setting the screen saver to timeout after 5 minutes... This will initially fix my issue, but i'd be interested in finding out why is will not prompt me for a password?

Comment: When you start that remote system, does it now stop with the "welcome" screen? (It should, as long as there is more than one account & passwords are required.)    Have you installed any other network providers that could interfere with authentication?  Check the registry key at  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services\fPromptForPassword - it should be set to 1; could it have been changed at some point?

Comment: Hi, thanks again.

I didn't have this entry so I added it as a REG_DWORD and set it to a 1, but it still doesn't prompt me for a username/password and RDP as acting like a VNC session rather than RDP...

Comment: Argh! I feel a little stupid now! Inside VirtualBox I had enabled Remote Display which seems to have somehow interfered with Windows own RDP... I have disabled it in Oracle VirtualBox manager and it now works as expected. My apologies and thank you for sticking with me on this one!

Comment: Well, at least you found it.  It's not always easy to track what one has configured that can interfere.  Glad it's resolved now.